# SPFX + TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function error in babel-loader

Tags: docx, spfx, babel-loader

I want to create SharePoint webpart where I am using Docx npm module to generate docs but due to some loader related error I have added the webpack and added **babel-loader** in the webpack but I am getting below error while using **gulp bundle **command.

```
**Error - [webpack] 'dist':                                                                                                                                                                                                        r or be explicitly marked as ignored
./lib/webparts/docxWebpart/DocxWebpartWebPart.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (D:/Practice/DocxCreatorPOC/DocxReactPOC/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:44:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/Practice/DocxCreatorPOC/DocxReactPOC/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:39:12)**
```

babel-loader:9.1

Node: 16.20.1

NPM: 9.8.1

OS: Windows 10

Below is my gulpfile.js code looks like for webpack:

```
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
  additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
    generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    );

    return generatedConfiguration;
  }
});
build.initialize(require('gulp'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Babel-loader 9 only works with webpack 5 but SharePoint framework uses webpack 4. Downgrading to babel-loader 8.2.5 (the last version of 8) will get rid of this error.